# EF 5 Code First DbMigration automation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 5 with the Code First Approach.

I'm having trouble setting the default `DateTime` value of a column to a `(getdateutc())`

What I want to do is have EF set up tables with this value speficied, and the only way I've found that it's possible is to use `DbMigrations` (Up and Down methods). Are the any other ways ?

I have a base class looking like this

```
 public abstract class BASE_AUDITED : BASE
 {              
      [IgnoreDataMember, IgnoreMap]
      public DateTime Created { get; set; }

      [IgnoreDataMember, IgnoreMap]
      public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

      [MaxLength(50)]
      [IgnoreDataMember, IgnoreMap]
      public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

      [MaxLength(50)]
      [IgnoreDataMember, IgnoreMap]
      public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
 }

 public abstract class BASE 
 {
      [IgnoreMap]
      public int id { get; set; }
 }
```

And a bunch of classes inheriting from it.
What I'd like to do is be able to access the model (using `fluentAPI` for mapping)in the DBMigrations Up method, and write a loop there to take care of all the the objects inheriting from `Base_audited`

In other words I'm trying to avoid writing following code for each and every object I add,

```
AlterColumn("T70_AccountService.CONTACT", "TestClmn", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getutcdate())"));
```

But rather have smth like this

```
 var types = ReflectionHelper.TypesImplementingInterface(typeof (BASE_AUDITED));
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
               var tableName = Context.FindTableNameFor(type);
               AlterColumn(tableName , "Created", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getutcdate())"));
               AlterColumn(tableName , "Modified", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getutcdate())"));

            }
```

In short - I cannot find what table is the object mapped to in the DbMigrations Up method..

```
 var tableName = Context.FindTableNameFor(type);
```

Comment: C# class names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: I think so Too! Tell that to our architect :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've implemented, and that seems to work fine with some overhead (of recreating contrains) is to use the "`Seed`" method of the migration configuration:

```
  protected override void Seed(AccountServiceEntities context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            #region SET Defaults for Audit Fields

            var types = ReflectionHelper.GetEnumerableOfType<BASE_AUDITED>();
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var method = typeof(ContextExtensions).GetMethod("GetTableName");
                var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type.GetType());
                var table = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { context });

                var constraintName = string.Format("DF__{0}__", type.GetType().Name);

                CreateDefaultCronstraint(context, table, constraintName, "Created");
                CreateDefaultCronstraint(context, table, constraintName, "Modified");

            }

            #endregion...
```

And here's the modified Context extentions class that extract the table name from the Context
public static class ContextExtensions
    {

```
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        return objectContext.GetTableName2<T>();
    }

    public static string GetTableName2<T>(this ObjectContext context) where T : class
    {
        var sql = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToTraceString();
        var regex = new Regex("FROM (?<table>.*) AS");
        var match = regex.Match(sql);

        var table = match.Groups["table"].Value;
        return table;
    }
}
```