# Is it possible to extent FluentApiMapper to set the default value ?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I'm using  EF 5 Code Fist and specifying some custom object to table mapping with the fluent API. Smth like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
   //Account Service
   modelBuilder.Entity<ACCOUNT>().ToTable("ACCOUNT", "T70_AccountService");
    ...
   modelBuilder.Entity<ACCOUNT>()
     .Property(p => p.Created).HasColumnType("DateTime")
     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

What I would like to be able to do is add an extetion that would allow to to add

```
 .HasDefaultValue('(getdateutc()');
```

Is that possible ? Any ideas how ?

Comment: You could simply use the constructor of the POCO class to initialize new objects with default values.

Comment: Could you show an example of how to do this?

Comment: @JoeFrambach Where your class is defined do something like this- public class ACCOUNT { public ACCOUNT() { Created = DateTime.Now; } public DateTime Created { get; set; } } - this is known as a Default Constructor for the class. It is also possible to create overloaded constructors with parameters which you can use to create the new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: no, there is no API (yet?) for setting default values in code-first.

The longer answer is: no. Second best (but far behind) is to use a database initializer to send a DDL query to the database:

```
protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "ALTER TABLE [T70_AccountService] ADD DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [Created]");
}
```

Comment: Well, this is a solution. Any ideas how I could find all the objects, and the names of the table's that they're mapped to ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294780/ef-5-code-first-dbmigration-automation

Comment: Should be simple, but isn't. The mapping information is buried miles deep in the MetadataWorkspace. I hope that will change one day.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, code first now supports this. In the "Up()" method of the generated migration, specify a default with the following syntax:

```
AddColumn("[table name]", "[column name]", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: false));
```